# Asset Library is Missing in Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, video, video-richmedia

I am trying to create an Asset library to store some videos and pictures.

Asset library is the most convenient one for this purpose, but I am not able to find Asset Library when I attempt to add an app.

Does SharePoint 2013 Foundation support Asset Library? if so, how can I activate it? 
I have read in one of the forum posts saying that you need to enable publishing features which ,I believe, is not Foundation feature. However, in the comparison table it is stated that

Asset Library Enhancements/Video Support is in Foundation too. But I dont seem to find/use this.

Can you help with this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Asset Library [is supported by SharePoint 2013 Foundation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-up-an-asset-library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-HA102785730.aspx). I'm presuming you have sufficient permission to add an app, but that you don't see the Asset Library App?!

Unfortunately, the Video and Rich Media feature is not part of Sharepoint 2013 Foundation, so you need to use Server version to add videos and rich content.

[image]

Comment: @benny-sckogberg thanks for your answer. I am system admin.. so I have all the permissions, but I cannot see Asset Library. my aim is to put some videos which is in one of the document libraries into a page. I believe I need to use old techniques to achieve this. So Foundation does not support viewing videos which are in asset library?

Comment: @AnarchistGeek You're welcome. You are nolt (or should not) be able tu upload videos in the Asset Library as they are not supported in Foundation. But if you, I see no reason why you at least should be able to download them and view them locally.